# Log in to domain A then use domain A's cookies for domain B

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm using CookieAwareWebClient to log in and interact with a web API.  My client has the login service in a subdomain and the API in a different subdomain (or on a different domain entirely.. not sure).  But they're different enough that the client is not passing in the cookie once it is set.  Please see below...

```
//call the web client
CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
client.BaseAddress = @"WEB_API_DOMAIN_NAME";

//establish login data
Dictionary<string, string> loginData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
loginData.Add("username", SCSettings.Default.username);
loginData.Add("password", SCSettings.Default.password);

//create login string from dictionary
string loginJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginData);

//begin login
string bouncerBaseUri = @"LOGIN_SERVICE_DOMAIN_NAME";
string bouncerUri = String.Format(@"{0}v1/auth/session/", bouncerBaseUri);
client.UploadString(bouncerUri, "POST", loginJson);

//test... NOM NOM NOM cookies
//Uri cookieUri = new Uri(bouncerBaseUri);
//Cookie sessionCookie = Helpers.GetSpecificCookie(client.CookieContainer, cookieUri, "bouncer");

//fails... cookie is not passed
string test = client.DownloadString("/api/reports/v1/reportconfig/");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I needed to add the cookie to the container under a different Uri.

```
//get the cookie
Uri loginUri = new Uri(bouncerBaseUri);
Cookie sessionCookie = Helpers.GetSpecificCookie(client.CookieContainer, loginUri , "bouncer");

//add to the container under a different Uri
Uri webApiBaseUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress);
client.CookieContainer.Add(webApiBaseUri, sessionCookie);
```

`GetSpecificCookie` simply returns the specified cookie

```
public static Cookie GetSpecificCookie(CookieContainer cookieJar, Uri domain, string cookieName)
{
    CookieCollection scCookies = cookieJar.GetCookies(domain);
    Cookie cookie = scCookies[cookieName];

    return cookie;
}
```